# Need to implement Threading and semaphore in C# console application

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, semaphore

Goal is to trigger a url ( reports from the report server).

I've a sql-request which returns rows. Suppose it returns 1000 rows , I need to trigger all those URLs, in batch or in chunk of 100 at one time so that server performance will not hamper.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           Console.WriteLine("hello");
            string connectionString = "Server=Mayank-Pc;Database=reportserver;User=sa;Password=mayank;Trusted_Connection=False;";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("done");

            string strSQLQuery = string.Empty;
            strSQLQuery = @"SELECT top 3 'mayank-pc' AS ServerName,C.Path AS ReportPath,'salesorderid=43659'  Parameter,0 MaxTimeDataRetrievalSeconds,0 MinTimeDataRetrievalSeconds,99 TotalCount FROM Catalog C where  path like '/Reports/Sales%'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLQuery, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable("allPrograms");
            adapt.Fill(table);

            int dtCount;
            dtCount = table.Rows.Count;
            Console.WriteLine(dtCount);
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            { //http:// mayank-pc/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Reports/Sales&rs:Command=Render&salesorderid=43659
                string strPath = "http://" + dr["ServerName"].ToString() + "/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" + dr["ReportPath"].ToString() + "&rs:Command=Render&" + dr["Parameter"].ToString();
                Console.Write(strPath + "\n");
                //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", strPath);
                WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(strPath);
                myRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mayank", "India@");
                myRequest.Method = "GET";
                myRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
                // Return the response. 

                try
                {
                    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
                    Console.Write("Success" + "\n");
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    Console.Write("Error:" + e.ToString() + "\n");
                }                
            }
            Console.Read();        
        }

        public SqlConnection objConn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you should structure your methods approprietly. Create a worker-method to work on your requests. Yet I believe you won't be able to run 100 requests concurrently...

Answer (score 0):

Will give you 100 tasks and then wait for all to complete. Put it inside some kind of while if you want it to rerun.

```
        int threads = 100;
        Task[] tasks = new Task[threads];

        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    //Dostuffs
                });
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```